# How to add keywords to the psi class created by the intellij plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm working on my first Intellij plug-in which generates lot of java static inner classes in the file that the user is currently working on. I'm able to generate the inner classes and add fields to that inner class, But the generated inner classes are non static how can i make the inner classes static? 
With a litle of research I know this can be acheived by `psiFactory.createClassFromText()`but for some reason I don't want to use this method.

I think in few of the projects the  same is acheived using the below code

```
mClass.addBefore(mFactory.createKeyword("static", mClass), mClass.findInnerClassByName(Utils.getInnerClassName(), true));
```

but  I'm not able to make the same work for me, here is my code for creating inner classes

```
 private void createStaticInnerClass(String className) {
    PsiClass innerClass = psiFactory.createClass(className.trim());
    addFieldsToClass(innerClass);
    psiClass.add(subClass);

}
```

can someone please enlighten me on how can I make that innerclass static?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I'm able to make a static inner class by the below one line magical code `innerclass.getModifierList().setModifierProperty("static", true);`